# Flask: sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: blog_post

Tags: python, sqlite, консоль, flask, sqlalchemy

Вот вроде бы и класс есть, но почему-то выскакивает ошибка, что таблицы нету и я плохо понимаю как ее обработать, находил варианты ответа на подобный вопрос, но не один не подошел.

Traceback:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: blog_post

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2450, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1867, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "D:\Programming\Python\Python+Flask_Udemy\Social_Blog\puppyblog\core\views.py", line 11, in index
    blog_posts = BlogPost.query.order_by(BlogPost.date.desc()).paginate(page=page,per_page=5)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\flask_sqlalchemy\__init__.py", line 496, in paginate
    items = self.limit(per_page).offset((page - 1) * per_page).all()
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3373, in all
    return list(self)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3535, in __iter__
    return self._execute_and_instances(context)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py", line 3560, in _execute_and_instances
    result = conn.execute(querycontext.statement, self._params)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1011, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py", line 298, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1124, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1316, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1510, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\util\compat.py", line 182, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\base.py", line 1276, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "C:\Python39\Lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\default.py", line 608, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: blog_post
[SQL: SELECT blog_post.id AS blog_post_id, blog_post.user_id AS blog_post_user_id, blog_post.date AS blog_post_date, blog_post.title AS blog_post_title, blog_post.text AS blog_post_text
FROM blog_post ORDER BY blog_post.date DESC
 LIMIT ? OFFSET ?]
[parameters: (5, 0)]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/13/e3q8)
```

models.py

```
 from puppyblog import db, login_manager
    from datetime import datetime
    from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash,check_password_hash
    from flask_login import UserMixin
    # By inheriting the UserMixin we get access to a lot of built-in attributes
    # which we will be able to call in our views!
    # is_authenticated()
    # is_active()
    # is_anonymous()
    # get_id()
    
    # The user_loader decorator allows flask-login to load the current user
    # and grab their id.
    
    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        return User.query.get(user_id)
    
    class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    
        # Create a table in the db
        __tablename__ = 'users'
    
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
        profile_image = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default_profile.png')
        email = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
        username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
        password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
        # This connects BlogPosts to a User Author.
        posts = db.relationship('BlogPost', backref='author', lazy=True)
    
        def __init__(self, email, username, password):
            self.email = email
            self.username = username
            self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)
    
        def check_password(self,password):
            # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23432478/flask-generate-password-hash-not-constant-output
            return check_password_hash(self.password_hash,password)
    
        def __repr__(self):
            return f"UserName: {self.username}"
    
    class BlogPost(db.Model):

        __tablename__ = 'blog_post'

        # Setup the relationship to the User table
        users = db.relationship(User)
    
        # Model for the Blog Posts on Website
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        # Notice how we connect the BlogPost to a particular author
        user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'), nullable=False)
        date = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
        title = db.Column(db.String(140), nullable=False)
        text = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    
        def __init__(self, title, text, user_id):
            self.title = title
            self.text = text
            self.user_id =user_id
    
    
        def __repr__(self):
            return f"Post Id: {self.id} --- Date: {self.date} --- Title: {self.title}"
```

**init**.py

```
# puppycompanyblog/__init__.py
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'mysecret'

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///'+os.path.join(basedir, 'data.sqlite')
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
Migrate(app,db)

########################

login_manager = LoginManager()

login_manager.init_app(app)
login_manager.login_view = 'users.login'

########################
from puppyblog.core.views import core
from puppyblog.users.views import users
from puppyblog.error_pages.handlers import error_pages
from puppyblog.blog_posts.views import blog_posts

app.register_blueprint(core)
app.register_blueprint(users)
app.register_blueprint(blog_posts)
app.register_blueprint(error_pages)
```

Comment: SQLiteStudio скачайте и посмотрите, есть ли там такая таблица

Comment: SQLiteStudio скачал, но возникла проблема, я не совсем понимаю, как проверить в SQliteStudio приложение flask на наличие определенной таблицы,
Не могли бы в дать ссылки на какие-то ресурсы, где можно было бы это посмотреть?

Comment: у вас в корне проекта база есть data.sqlite? вам надо в sqllitestudio просто указать путь к этой базе и она появится

Comment: Я не совсем увидел, где там можно указать путь, через импорт, я правильно понимаю?

Comment: я попробовал импортировать, но возникла проблема, что я не могу нажать на кнопку "Finish", хотя все обязательные опции, я выбрал, в чем может быть проблема?

Comment: не подскажете как исправить?

Comment: SqlLiteSutio->DataBase->Add database->файл (указать существующий файл data.sqlite, в корне проекта должен лежать)